# How to convert python raw code to shellcode for specific arch and sys?

Tags: python, compiler

Is there any tool or python library for converting python code to shellcode for specific architecture (ex. x86) and system (ex. Windows Vista)?

For instance I would like to convert:

```
print "This is sample text"
```

to something like:

```
\x92\x12\xa1\xa2\x00...
```

In brief, I need the tool or library that would have similar functionality to msfvenom written in ruby. I tried converting .py to .pyc, then extracting shellcode from it by using py_compile and binascii with hexlify libraries but it was not i wanted. Is it possible to convert python code to shellcode in any way? Maybe is there any compilator to binary of python code?

Comment: As you only mention the target OS as example, are you interested in other OSes than Windows – or would "Windows only" be acceptable? If so, [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) would be an example. The latest downloads on Sourceforge are years old; but [the source](https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk) has at least been updated a year ago. Supports Python 2 and 3.